# Oozie 5.2.1 with hadoop 2.7.2

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Getting the following error when I try to validate my workflow.xml using *oozie validate Workflow.xml*

**Error: E0701: XML schema error, /root/mr-wordcount/Workflow.xml, org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl' is not recognized.**

**this is my workflow.xml**

```xml
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:1.0" name="sample-wf" >
 <start to='streaming1' />
    <action name='streaming1'>
        <map-reduce>
           <resource-manager>${ressourcesmanager}</resource-manager>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/output/${outputDir}"/>
            </prepare>
            <streaming>
                <mapper>mapper.py</mapper>
                <reducer>reducer.py</reducer>
            </streaming>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>

                  <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/root/input/purchases.txt</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>out-oozie</value>
                </property></configuration>
            <file>mapper.py#mapper.py</file>
            <file>reducer.py#reducer.py</file>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Map/Reduce failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

this is my job.properties:

```
nameNode=hdfs://hadoop-master:9000
ressourcesmanager=hadoop-master:8032
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true


oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/root/tpOozie
```

Anyone who faced and resolved a similar issue in the past?

Comment: Yarn doesn't have a "job tracker" anymore. Are you sure you're copying the most up to date examples?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I changed the configuration sorry. But, I still have the same error :(

Comment: It's a "Resource Manager", not "Resources"

Comment: I've only used recently used Oozie for Spark job scheduling, not mapreduce, so unfortunately I don't recognize your error. Airflow is easier to work with than Oozie as well